# How to determine location of a user?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to find code that will determine the current location of a user via GPS. For example, if a user went to my webpage and that user was browsing from France, the page would read back their current location in text. I'm thinking JavaScript might do the trick, but I'm not sure.

Comment: My desktop computer doesn't have GPS, my iPod Touch doesn't have GPS, and my smartphone is set up to disallow use of my location information; so be prepared to use it if you get it, but do something sensible when you don't have the location.

Comment: The best thing you can do is do a WHOIS on the IP (Geo IP table) to find out the location of where the IP comes from.  Other than that, unless the browser offers a specific API and you are using a custom web server, recording this information is unfeasable.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have much to do with the Global Positioning System (GPS), which is a network of satellites sending out the current time - at least, not directly.

You can use the [HTML5 Geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) to detect where the user's browser *says* it's located, but even if they are telling you the truth, you don't know where they got that information.

Or, you could guess their location from their IP address via a GeoIP database, but that's imprecise and error-prone.

Comment: An up to date Geo IP location database should be fairly accurate, but you have to pay for those. Free versions are less accurate, but they're right most of the time.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt I was more referring to the fact that a user physically located in France but going through a proxy server to the US will show up as one thing to GeoIP and another to the Geolocation API.

Comment: I see. That's true, but I have to say; How many users are surfing through a Proxy or VPN located in another country? I still think a Geo IP database is perfectly fine for most applications. I also +1'd your answer.

Comment: It's not the HTML5 Geolocation API, it's the W3C Geolocation API. It's not part of HTML5.

Comment: Actually it is referred to as the HTML5 Geolocation API, and you can check that out at W3C's web site: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: Here is an example you can run in your browser and the code behind it. http://maxheapsize.com/2009/04/11/getting-the-browsers-geolocation-with-html-5/